# Put and get in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dreamweaver

How to get or put files from local to ftp server in Microsoft Visual 2010, equivalent options from Dreamweaver put/get ? 
And is there in VS option to upload and download (in DW ctrl + shift U/D) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the web project and select `Publish`. There are several different options.

See [How to: Deploy a Web Site Project by Using the Publish Web Site Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx) for details.

> The target location can be a local or shared folder, **an FTP site**, or a Web site that you access with a URL. You must have permissions to create and write files in the target location.

(emphasis mine)